# Array of json from external file is not setting up the state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react. And I am trying to `setState` on `componentDidMount()` function with external file contains `Array of Data` but it is not setting up the state. It shows empty every time I refresh the page.

app.js

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import newData from './data.js';


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            data : []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({data: newData});
        console.log(this.state.data)
    }

    
    render(){
    return (
        <div>Hello</div>
        )
    }

}
```

data.js

```
const newData = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "GoodName",
    },
]


export default newData
```

I have also tried by changing the format of data and wrap into a a `Seed.function` like

```
window.Seed = (function() {

    const newData = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'GoodName',
        },
    ];
    return {newData: newData };
}());
```

And tried to `setState` by

```
this.setState({data: Seed.newData});
```

But it says, `Seed is not defined`

- *Should I need to import external json array file in `index.html` instead of App.js* ?
- *Should I need to use `map` function **or** `for of` loop to iterate every element in data before setting state* ?

I have tried many times but it is still not working.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state.data` is not immediately available after calling `setState`. Check:
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-doesnt-react-update-thisstate-synchronously

Try to stick `console.log` in `render` instead to see the contents of an array.

Comment: Thanks, It Worked, But When I `console.log(this.state.data)` then it is showing it `four times`, I don't think it is looping it four times, Because I am not using any loop and Not using any map and Also array is not long enough

Comment: Check last paragraph of: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount
It generally should trigger re-render twice, not sure why you get log shown 4x.